# Copy file from a vm not reachable via ssh

Tags: ssh, vmware, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a virtual machine (RHEL 7) on VMware that is not reachable via ssh due to some issues that we are trying to solve. 
I need to extract a file from this vm that is accessible only via vmware console. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Does your VM have functionnal network ?

If so, you can use `netcat`:

- On destination machine/VM: `nc -l -p 10000 > file`
- On source VM: `cat src_file|nc dest_machine 10000`.

Comment: The file I have to copy is a dump of a disk created with dd, so cat is not suitable for this scenario. Which command could I use instead cat?

Comment: You can use `dd if=<your disk> | nc <host> <port>`

Comment: the command shows connection refused. I tried on 1234 or 10000 port without success

Comment: The two machines are on the same physical LAN ? Check firewall or network settings....